# Переменные в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Мне один раз приходилось решать пример с числами, где пришлось заняться преобразованием типов  плюс объявить альтернативные переменные с проверкой ввода.
Это неужели и для работы со строками необходима такая позиция? Или в работе со строками можно обойтись классом?

Я имею в виду именно эту позицию, как работа с альтернативными переменными.
Ну а то что Delphi - вынос мозга. Кто бы сомневался

```
b1 := (InputBox('Ввод числа b', 'Введите число b:', ''));
b := StrToFloat(b1);
```

Comment: Действительно! Мало того, что Delfi (Delphi ??)... Вынос мозга...

Comment: Так в чём же проблема-то. В желании на выходе InputBox получать Float? Вспомогательная функция не поможет? Или в чём-то ещё?

Comment: У меня было большое желание записать всё одной строкой
b := StrToFloat(InputBox('Ввод числа', 'Введите число:', ''));

В связи с чем и вопрос, что даёт ввод альтернативной переменной. Почему лучше вариант в двух строках, нежели одной строкой?

Comment: @Prox А откуда информация, что он вообще "лучше"?

Comment: Не знаю, так попросили сделать, правда пришлось объявлять дополнительно альтернативные переменные перед началом кода как например
var a : double;
a1 : string;(это в случае если брать ввод данных двумя строками)
Вот интересно мне, как лучше, так или иначе? Потому что я с трудом после С++ сижу в Delphi и вижу, сколько тут заморочек. В основном всё приходится пробовать и проверять

Comment: Лучше здесь перейти на си и не ломать людям мозг криво заданными вопросами.

Comment: да возились вообще с утилитой, у которой синтаксис Паскаля(Делфи), но своих команд много. Одно точно ясно, что С++, что Паскаль - каждый сносит мозг по своему)))

Comment: Комментарии нельзя принять как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно решить задачу тремя основными способами:

1. Написать класс, который выводит InputBox, получает с нее данные, выполняет все необходимые действия (проверка, обработка...). Из плюсов - в основной программе будет мало кода.
2. Сделать вашим способом - в одну строку, заключив код в try-except.
3. Сделать, как сказано, получить строку, проверить значение (любым доступным способом), а затем выполнить конвертацию типов (в этом собственно и преимущество перед (2) - по большому счету не нужен вам try-except блок).